# Change color of specific menu item on hover

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I created this bit of code. As you can see whenever I hover over `nav li` I want `nav li a` to change its color.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">test</a>
            <a href="#">test2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
a {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("nav li").hover(function() {
        $("nav li a").css("color", "#02baff");
    }, function() {
        $("nav li a").css("color", "");
    });
});
```

But my problem is the this:

[image]

All the a tags change color when I hover over one. How do I make this specific item to change not all of them only the a tag I'm hovering over.

I created a jsfiddle for you guys who are willing to help.
https://jsfiddle.net/4oL2p351/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using like this,

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('a').css("color","#02baff");

            },function(){
                $(this).find('a').css("color","");
    });
});
});
```

Comment: aah, I forgot about find! Thanks i will accept in a bit.

Comment: @Kevin.a that's the same fiddle and still doesn't do what you asked...?

Comment: ... which is what I told you in my answer. Except with the added benefit of using CSS only over JS so the effect is hardware accelerated